# This page isn’t working right nowIf the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405 trying to fix this problem in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**When I click on delete button, I am getting an error: This page isn’t working right now the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405**

**This is mine view.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView  
from .models import Post, TaskCategory
from .forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DeletePostView(DetailView):
      model = Post
      template_name = 'delete_post.html'
      success_url = reverse_lazy('PostPage')
```

**urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import path
# from . import views
from .views import PostHomeView,PostDetail,NavFooter,PostPageView,AddPost,UpdatePost,DeletePostView

urlpatterns = [
path('', PostHomeView.as_view(), name ='home'),
path('PostDetail/<int:pk>', PostDetail.as_view(), name ='post_detail'),
path('PostPage/', PostPageView, name ='post_page'),
path('AddPost/', AddPost.as_view(), name = 'add_post'),
path('PostDetail/UpdatePost/<int:pk>', UpdatePost.as_view(), name = 'update'),
path('DeletePost/<int:pk>/', DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'delete'),
]
```

**HTML delete_page.html file:**

```
{% extends "nav_footer.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="form-group">
   <p>{{ post.task_title }}</p>
   <p>{{ post.task_discription }}</p>
   <p>{{ post.recommended_tools }}</p>
   <p>{{ post.budget }}</p>
   <form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
   </form>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

**And this is modes.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class TaskCategory(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title

 class Post(models.Model):
     task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     task_discription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + str(self.task_category) + ' | ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + str(self.budget) + ' | ' + str(self.id)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**I think the problem is somewhere revers_lazy function, I am not sure about that**

Answer (score 1):

HTTP error 405 is "Method Not Allowed". This means that you are trying to perform some action that is not defined or allowed.

Your problem is that you are using "DetailView" in your "DeletePostView", it should be using "DeleteView" instead.

```
class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    ....
```

The thing here is that "DetailView" does not have the post method defined.